# How to use Back button on Telegraf.js

Tags: node.js

I get menu contents at mysql. 
For example:

```
id    name         parent_id
1     Mevalar      0
2     Sabzovotlar  0
3     Olmalar      2
4     Qovunlar     1
5     Shirin       3
```

If I click the menu content [ Mevalar, Sabzovotlar ]

```
next -> click Mevalar content [ Olmalar, Back]
next -> click olmalar content [ Shirin , Back]
next -> click Back content [Olmalar, Back]
next -> click Back content [Mevalar, Sabzovotlar]
```

I write all code 1.2.3 steps are working but. How to write code to Back button?